# Deserialize Json data generated by different Json.Net lib

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, json.net

Using Json.Net, can you deserialize Json data that was generated in a different Json.Net lib (I'm using the .Net4 and windows phone libs of Json.Net)? This is what I have so far:

I have a Map Editor created in XNA (.Net 4) that can serialize and deserialize Json data using Json.Net (for .Net). I create a struct to store the data and specify what data properties I want serizalized, like so:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public struct LevelData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RowCount")]
    private int RowCount;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ColCount")]
    private int ColCount;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NodeSize")]
    private int NodeSize;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "LevelNodes")]
    private List<Node> LevelNodes;

    public LevelData(int rowCount, int colCount, int nodeSize, List<Node> nodes)
    {
        RowCount = rowCount;
        ColCount = colCount;
        NodeSize = nodeSize;
        LevelNodes = nodes;
    }
}
```

And the Node class is as follows:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Node
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ID")]
    private int mId;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Position")]
    private Vector2 mPosition;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Type")]
    private NodeType mType;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Neighbours")]
    private List<int> mNeighbours;

    ....
}
```

I also have a windows phone xna game, that reads in the Json data created from the map editor, also using Json.Net (for windows phone). This game has LevelData and Node, which are exactly the same as the Map Editor struct and class.

Json.Net provides a different lib for .Net 4 and windows phone. However, they do not seem to have the same functionality. When the windows phone game reads in the json data created from the Map Editor, it fails to deserialize the data, with the following error:

```
Error getting value from 'mRowCount' on 'LevelData'.
```

With the following printed out in the Debug window:

```
 A first chance exception of type 'System.FieldAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
 A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
 A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

I can solve this issue by making the member variables public, and not private. But then it complains that it does not recognize Vector2:

```
Error converting value "12, 12" to type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2'. Line 8, position 27.
```

With the following printed out in the Debug window:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

Where is the Json data created by the Map Editor:

```
{
    "RowCount": 20,
    "ColCount": 20,
    "NodeSize": 25,
    "LevelNodes": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Position": "12, 12",
            "Type": 1,
            "Neighbours": [
                2,
                21
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Buildings": []
}
```

Edit: Here is how I serialize and deserialize the data.

```
String json = Json.ConvertToJson<LevelData>(levelData);

public static class Json
{
    // Serialize Object to Json
    public static string ConvertToJson<T>(T obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
    }

    public static T ConvertFromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Just a note: I can serialize and deserialize the json in the map editor (.Net) just fine, it supports private json properties and Vector2. The issue is when I go to deserialize json data, which was generated in the Map Editor, in the windows phone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try doing is introducing your own converter for the Vector2 type;

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Node {
  ...

  [JsonConverter(typeof(Vector2Converter))]
  public Vector2 Position { get; set; }

  ...
}
```

`Vector2Converter` is a type deriving from Json.Net's `JsonConverter`.

```
public class Vector2Converter : JsonConverter {
  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
    return (objectType == typeof(Vector2));
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    return serializer.Deserialize<Vector2>(reader);
  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)  {
    // Implement this if you're serialising back into JSON
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

I haven't tried this in the particular case of `Vector2`s so can't confirm it'll definitely work out of the box. If it doesn't in your `ReadJson` implementation you can start looking into making use of the `Value` property on the `JsonReader`. This returns an `object` that you can cast to other types and potentially create a new `Vector2` using the data from. If that doesn't work you may need to look into an even more involved `JsonConverter` where you react to the tokens on the reader (`TokenType`, etc)

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I didn't have to go down that route, as I suspect I will encounter this issue with many other object types. Don't understand why they can do it for the .Net version, but no windows phone. Maybe it is for silverlight?

Comment: I've certainly never encountered this issue before and looking at `Vector2` (I've not done any XNA work) I can't see anything peculiar with it (other than being a `struct`, but then so is `DateTime`). The other thing to look at is how are you serialising the data? What `TypeNameHandling` and `TypeNameAssemblyFormat` options are you giving the `JsonSerializer`?

Comment: I think I am seeing the problem. I am actually using JsonConvert, and not JsonSerializer itself. I've edited my original post to show how I serialize the data. I've also tried using the following JsonSettings `Formatting.Indented, TypeNameHandling.All, FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full` but it still complained about the Vector2.

Comment: I think you'll want to use `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple` as `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full` requires version numbers on assemblies to match which they probably don't between desktop and phone. (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.formatterassemblystyle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A more complete answer to future viewers having issues serializing and deserializing Vector2's or other similar objects. I'm having the issue in straight Windows, not WinPhone like OP.

It's possible to setup the custom Vector2 deserializer on the serialization object itself rather than each Vector2 property that needs to be serialized, like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new Vector2Converter());
YourType yourObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>(fileContents, settings);
```

That keeps us from having to decorate every Vector2 property.

Additionally, the full implementation of the converter I'm using, with read and write implemented, is:

```
public class Vector2Converter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return (objectType == typeof(Vector2));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var properties = jsonObject.Properties().ToList();
        return new Vector2
        {
            X = (float)properties[0].Value,
            Y = (float)properties[1].Value
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        Vector2 v = (Vector2)value;
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("X");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, v.X);
        writer.WritePropertyName("Y");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, v.Y);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```